# Redis client quite slow when getting items (80ms or worse)

Tags: node.js, performance, express, redis, digital-ocean

My redis client is quite slow to grab items - the db is hosted on a DigitalOcean basic plan.

My code to execute fetches is as follows:

```js
const client = require('../database/redis') // exports result of createClient({url})

let cc = client;
const cacheActions= await cc.GET(userID+'actions')
module.exports.startActions = async (sessionID, userID, ... /*string params*/) => {

if (!cc || !cc.isOpen) cc = await client.connect()

let ct = performance.now()

// schedule cron job
const task = cron.schedule('*/6 * * * * *', async () => {

        ct = performance.now()

        // get all data from cache, put it in an object
        const id = userID.toString()

        const cacheActions= await cc.GET(userID+'actions')
        console.log('cache fetched in ' + (performance.now() - ct) + ' ms.')
        ct = performance.now()

            if (cacheActions) {
                actionData = JSON.parse(cacheActions);
            } else {
                // mongoose / mongodb is defined already [not shown]
                const actions = await Action.findOne({user: userID})
                const setter = await cc.SET(userID+'actions', JSON.stringify(actions), 
                'EX', 60)
                actionData = actions
            }
        console.log('action data fetched in ' + (performance.now() - ct) + ' ms.')
        ct = performance.now()

})
```

The result is as so:

```
cache fetched data in 82.16571399569511 ms.
action data fetched in 0.015850000083446503 ms.
```

The times are consistent across many iterations of the cron job.

While 80ms wouldn't necessarily be an issue on its own, I have about 5-6 iterations of this process, and for my project a 500+ms delay is way too long for a job that executes every 6 seconds (and I thought redis was meant to be extremely fast). Since virtually 100% of the time taken is from the `await cc.GET` line, I am assuming something is going on with the redis client (like the client trying to connect a bunch of times?), but I checked and the client only seems to connect once and nothing out-of-the-ordinary seems to be happening with the client. I'm not sure exactly what could be causing this issue. I'm wondering if it's my connection to DigitalOcean?

I tried to run `redis-benchmark -h [my host param] -p 25061 -a [my password for default user] -q` but I kept getting this error:

```
ERROR: failed to fetch reply from [my DigitalOcean host parameter]:25061
```

I don't think this would have anything to do with the slow times but I can't benchmark it so I can't tell if it's on my end or on theirs.